# Does Google actually duplicate files?

Tags: google-drive

When I duplicate a file in Google Drive (click "Make a copy"), is it actually duplicated on their servers? Or is it just a softlink to the original file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you right click on a file to "make a copy" it does indeed make a "hard copy."

I mapped the google drive to my device using the GDrive API to confirm that the files were created instantly after making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

How would anyone be able to tell? I suspect it could be that way until you modify the second file then it HAS to be two distinct files AND/OR incremental/differential version of changes from the original one